# RaptureXML kind of slow

Tags: iphone, ios, xml

I've recently switched from TBXML to RaptureXML, and even though pulling in information is much easier, there is a noticeable delay when I tap the tab bar button containing my xml table view.

In my viewDidLoad method I have the following"

```
events = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];

[self loadURL];
```

And my loadURL method is the following:

```
- (void)loadURL {

RXMLElement *rootXML = [RXMLElement elementFromURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"http://api.somexml.com/xml"]];

[rootXML iterateWithRootXPath:@"//event" usingBlock:^(RXMLElement *event) {
    [events addObject:[NSArray arrayWithObjects:
                       [event attribute:@"uri"],
                       [event attribute:@"displayName"],
                       [event attribute:@"type"],
                       nil]];  
}];

[rootXML iterateWithRootXPath:@"//location" usingBlock: ^(RXMLElement *location) {
    [events addObject:[NSArray arrayWithObjects:
                       [location attribute:@"city"],
                       [location attribute:@"lat"],
                       [location attribute:@"lng"],
                       nil]]; 
}];

[rootXML iterateWithRootXPath:@"//start" usingBlock:^(RXMLElement *start) {
    [events addObject:[NSArray arrayWithObjects:
                       [start attribute:@"time"],
                       [start attribute:@"date"],
                       nil]]; 
}];



}
```

Is there something I can do to speed it up? Also when I assign my row count as [events count] I'm getting 19 rows when I should only get 6. Please help.

Comment: You are synchronously requesting the XML within the main-thread which is a total No-No. Use an async way of loading the data.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Till is on the right track.  You need to parse on a background thread.  Do something like the following:

```
dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT, 0), ^{
    [self loadURL];

    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
        [tableView reloadData];
    });
});
```

You'll notice that I'm reloading the tableview on the main thread.  Updating interface elements on a background thread is a bit no-no.

Comment: You guys are awesome. I actually wanted to pull in the data asynchronously, but didn't know how. That makes a lot of sense!

Comment: Now something that I'm having trouble with is that for some reason, my row count is bringing in hundreds of rows, when there are actually only 6 events. I have a feeling it's making a row for each individual object that I'm adding to my array. Maybe I didn't add the objects correctly or assign my row count correctly.

Comment: I made that question an actual question on the site. Here's the link: [link]http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10377214/row-count-is-returning-the-incorrect-number-using-rapturexml