# Row Count Is Returning the incorrect number using RaptureXML

Tags: iphone, ios, xml, uitableview, nsmutablearray

I'm currently using RaptureXML to pull in data from a url tio display inside a table view. I've managed to grab every string I need and add it to my array, as you can see below:

```
- (void)loadURL {

RXMLElement *rootXML = [RXMLElement elementFromURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"http://api.somexml.com/xml"]];

NSLog(@"%@ %@", rootXML.tag, [rootXML attribute:@"totalEntries"]); 
[rootXML iterateWithRootXPath:@"//event" usingBlock:^(RXMLElement *event) {
    // NSLog(@"Event - URI: %@", [event attribute:@"uri"]);
    // NSLog(@"Event - Venue: %@", [event attribute:@"displayName"]);
    // NSLog(@"Event - Type: %@", [event attribute:@"type"]);

    [rootXML iterateWithRootXPath:@"//location" usingBlock: ^(RXMLElement *location) {
        // NSLog(@"Location - City: %@",[location attribute:@"city"]);
        // NSLog(@"Location - Latitude : %@",[location attribute:@"lat"]);
        // NSLog(@"Location - Longitude: %@",[location attribute:@"lng"]);

        [rootXML iterateWithRootXPath:@"//start" usingBlock:^(RXMLElement *start) {
            // NSLog(@"Start - Time: %@",[start attribute:@"time"]);
            // NSLog(@"Start - Date: %@",[start attribute:@"date"]);

            [rootXML iterateWithRootXPath:@"//performance" usingBlock:^(RXMLElement *performance) {
                // NSLog(@"Performance - Artist: %@",[start attribute:@"displayName"]);

                [events addObject:[NSArray arrayWithObjects:
                                   [event attribute:@"uri"],
                                   [event attribute:@"displayName"],
                                   [event attribute:@"type"],
                                   [location attribute:@"city"],
                                   [location attribute:@"lat"],
                                   [location attribute:@"lng"],
                                   [start attribute:@"time"],
                                   [start attribute:@"date"],
                                   [performance attribute:@"displayName"],
                                   nil]];                
            }];

        }];


    }];



}];

}
```

The problem is that when I assign the number of rows, it's returning a large number instead of 6.

```
 return [events count];
```

This is what the XML file looks like:

```
<resultsPage totalEntries="6" perPage="50" page="1" status="ok">
<results>
<event uri="http://somexml.com/xml" popularity="0.863682" displayName="Radio 1's Hackney 
Weekend 2012" id="9234656" type="Festival" status="ok">
<location city="London, UK" lng="-0.128" lat="51.5078"/>
<series displayName="Radio 1's Hackney Weekend"/>
<end time="" date="2012-06-24" datetime=""/>
<start time="" date="2012-06-23" datetime=""/>
<performance displayName="Lucy Labeaux" billingIndex="5" id="23336188" billing="headline">
<artist uri="http://www.somexml.com/artistxml" displayName="Lucy Labeaux" id="1168415">
<identifier href="http://somexml.com.xml" mbid="4593d49a-7f67-46ba-9ec0-126bd676286f"/>
</artist>
</performance>
```

Thank you for your help!

**

### Getting Error related to my array's objects.

**

So I figured out something from constantly running the code. If you look below I add objects to my array 3 separate times.

```
- (void)loadURL {

RXMLElement *rootXML = [RXMLElement elementFromURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"http://somexml.com/xml"]];

NSLog(@"%@ %@", rootXML.tag, [rootXML attribute:@"totalEntries"]);

[rootXML iterateWithRootXPath:@"//event" usingBlock:^(RXMLElement *event) {

    [events addObject:[NSArray arrayWithObjects:
                       [event attribute:@"uri"],
                       [event attribute:@"displayName"],
                       [event attribute:@"type"], nil]];
 }];

[rootXML iterateWithRootXPath:@"//location" usingBlock: ^(RXMLElement *location) {

    [events addObject:[NSArray arrayWithObjects:
                       [location attribute:@"city"],
                       [location attribute:@"lat"],
                       [location attribute:@"lng"],
                       nil]]; 
}];    

[rootXML iterateWithRootXPath:@"//start" usingBlock:^(RXMLElement *start) {

    [events addObject:[NSArray arrayWithObjects:
                       [start attribute:@"time"],
                       [start attribute:@"date"],
                       nil]]; 
}];

}
```

Now when I call my objects so I can link them to the interface I did the following:

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
EventsCell *cell = (EventsCell *)[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"EventsCell"];

cell.venueLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",[[events objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] objectAtIndex:2]];

return cell;
```

}

I realized that instead of creating a total of 8 objects at index, it's only creating 3. And everytime I add new objects it's adding it to those 3 indexes. For example if I assign my Venue Label to the objectAtIndex 2, I not only get 6 rows with the label displaying the type, but also another 6 displaying the time.

This is how my viewDidLoad looks:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
[super viewDidLoad];

self.events = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];

dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT, 0), ^{
    [self loadURL];

    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
        [self.tableView reloadData];
    });
});

}
```

Comment: Why are you iterating within iterations within even more iterations?  It looks like you're wanting to drill further down the xml, right?  If so, then edit your xpath, and bring all those statements outside those loops.  Don't ever use `iterateWithRootXPath:` when **inside** another loop.  You're going to get a whole lot more stuff than you want being duplicated.  That's probably why your parsing was so slow earlier.

Comment: That's exactly why I'm probably getting rows and rows of repetition. Now my problem is that when I iterate each statement outside of any loop, I can't add all the objects to my array together. I have to do this:

Comment: Here's what I'm trying to do but then I can't add all the objects at the same time, and therefore when I call them to display in the interface I get nothing beyond the first objects I added. [link]http://desmond.yfrog.com/Himg855/scaled.php?tn=0&server=855&filename=3ju.png&xsize=640&ysize=640

Comment: Seems you're adding them correctly.  It also seems that you're using an ivar to store the array, correct?  If so, you need to be using a retain property (or strong, if using ARC) to keep a retained reference to the created array.

Comment: I am using ARC and I've been using the strong property '@property (nonatomic, strong) NSMutableArray * events;' But when I call an object for the interface I get an error if I index anything above 2. Could it be that everytime I'm adding objects it replaces the older ones?

Comment: Do you ever initialize `events`?  Also, you're using `events` instead of using `self.events` to access the property, which is a big no no when initializing.  Are you initializing the array like `self.events = [NSMutableArray array];`?

Comment: Yeah I initialize it in viewDidLoad: as events = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init]; but you're right gahh. Let me try it with self.events

Comment: I added the self.events, and I got a an error: "[__NSArrayI objectAtIndex:]: index 3 beyond bounds [0 .. 2]" Which is what I was talking about. It only reads the first objects I add.

Comment: @sudorm-rf I think I've figured out what's happening. I edited the original question so you can see what the problem appears to be.

Comment: Can you just send me a link to the real xml that you're trying to parse?  I'll see if I can find time to take a quick look at it.  If it's sensitive, you can just email me.

Comment: @sudorm-rf Yeah it kind of is :/ Thank you so much just sent it to your email.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seeing that no one answered the question as an "answer" but left the answer in the comments, I'm going to just accept this as the answer.